# $S$ unit equation

Tags: number-theory

From experiments it seems $(1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n=2^a-3^b$ has finite solutions $(a,b,n)$, where $a,b,n$ are non-negative integers. From $S$ unit equation we know $(1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n=2^a+3^b$ has finite non-negative integer solutions. Is there any such result for $(1+\sqrt{2})^n+(1-\sqrt{2})^n=2^a-3^b$?

Comment: $f(n)=(1+\sqrt2)^n+(1-\sqrt2)^n$ satisfies $f(n+2)=f(n)+2f(n+1)$ so $f(n)$ is even, but $2^a-3^b$ is odd for $a>0$.

Comment: Thanks. However it seems result would be true for $5^a-3^a$.